# Using 8 6 4 2 = 6 in that order using only x - +

Tags: mathematics

One more question..
Using 8 6 4 2 = 6 in that order using only x - +

Answer (score 3):

> \begin{align*}8+6-4\cdot2&=6\\(8-6)\cdot4-2&=6\end{align*}

Not that difficult to find with a bit of bashing. There are probably more solutions somehow…